# Conflict between the same function which is once called outside function and then inside another function

Tags: javascript

The HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code I added here works perfectly but I have a very minor problem I.e, for ideal case, if I click on the name of item list, it should get a strike through. The code outcome also matches my expectation but only with the default list name. As soon as I add a new list item, the default list items are not getting strike though any more when they get a click. I guess it is due to conflict of `strikeThrought()` function (I may be wrong).

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (document.querySelector("input").value.length > 0) {
    input();
  }
})


document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (document.querySelector("input").value.length > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    input();
  }
})


deleteList();
strikeThrought();


function input() {
  var input = " " + document.querySelector("input").value;
  var li = document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
  var button = li.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
  button.innerHTML = "Delete";
  var span = li.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
  span.innerHTML = input;
  document.querySelector("input").value = "";

  deleteList();
  strikeThrought();
}


function deleteList() {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("li button").length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll("li button")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      for (var j = 0; j < document.querySelectorAll("li").length; j++) {
        this.parentNode.remove()
      }
    })
  }
}


function strikeThrought() {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("span").length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll("span")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("done");
    })
  }
}
```

```css
li{
  padding: 3px;
}
p{
  margin: 0;
}
.coolTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  word-spacing: -8px;
  color: tomato;
  text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 firebrick,
    -2px -2px 0 firebrick,
    -3px -3px 0 firebrick,
    -4px -4px 0 firebrick,
    -5px -5px 0 firebrick,
    -6px -6px 0 firebrick,
    -7px -7px 0 firebrick,
    -8px -8px 0 firebrick,
    -30px 20px 40px dimgrey;
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  <p>Get it done today</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type to enter">
  <button type="button">Enter</button>
  <ul>
    <li class="li0"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Notebook</span></li>
    <li class="li1"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Jello</span></li>
    <li class="li2"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Rice</span></li>
    <li class="li3"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Spinach</span></li>
    <li class="li4"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Birthday Cake</span></li>
    <li class="li5"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Candles</span></li>
  </ul>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works, but after page is loaded you assign the eventlister for method strikeTrough() twice and the method will be executed twice either. Add an alert() for test and you will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delegate the clicks to a higher element (`document` in my example below) and not try to add the event handlers every time a change is made.

```js
const inputButton = document.querySelector("button");
const inputField = document.querySelector("input")

inputButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (inputField.value.length > 0) {
    input();
  }
})


inputField.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (inputField.value.length > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    input();
  }
})

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if(event.target.nodeName == "SPAN")
    event.target.classList.toggle("done");
  else if(event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON" && event.target.classList.contains("toggle-button")) {
    event.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
})



function input() {
  var input = " " + document.querySelector("input").value;
  var li = document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
  var button = li.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
  button.innerHTML = "Delete";
  button.classList.add("toggle-button");
  var span = li.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
  span.innerHTML = input;
  document.querySelector("input").value = "";
}
```

```css
li{
  padding: 3px;
}
p{
  margin: 0;
}
.coolTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  word-spacing: -8px;
  color: tomato;
  text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 firebrick,
    -2px -2px 0 firebrick,
    -3px -3px 0 firebrick,
    -4px -4px 0 firebrick,
    -5px -5px 0 firebrick,
    -6px -6px 0 firebrick,
    -7px -7px 0 firebrick,
    -8px -8px 0 firebrick,
    -30px 20px 40px dimgrey;
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  <p>Get it done today</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type to enter">
  <button type="button">Enter</button>
  <ul>
    <li class="li0"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Notebook</span></li>
    <li class="li1"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Jello</span></li>
    <li class="li2"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Rice</span></li>
    <li class="li3"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Spinach</span></li>
    <li class="li4"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Birthday Cake</span></li>
    <li class="li5"><button class="toggle-button">Delete</button>  <span>Candles</span></li>
  </ul>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but your js code has a bug. The newly inserted list item is not getting deleted when clicked on '''Delete''' button

Comment: @SandheepKumarPatro Your original code which adds new elements is not adding the `toggle-button` class to the delete buttons if it did, this would work. I'll update the answer with the fix.